# Suppose $x_i>0$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,n$ and $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=1 \ldots$

Tags: inequality, summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

suppose $x_i>0$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,n$ and $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=1$ show that
$$\frac{x_1}{1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_n}+\frac{x_2}{1+x_1+x_3+\cdots+x_n}+\frac{x_3}{1+x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}+\cdots+\frac{x_n}{1+x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n-1}}\ge\frac{n}{2n-1}$$
**attempt**

from the equalitys i could rewrite
$1-x_1=x_2+\cdots+x_n$
and then
$$\frac{x_1}{1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_n}+\frac{x_2}{1+x_1+x_3+\cdots+x_n}+\frac{x_3}{1+x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}+\cdots+\frac{x_n}{1+x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n-1}}=\frac{x_1}{2-x_1}+\frac{x_2}{2-x_2}+\frac{x_3}{2-x_3}+\cdots+\frac{x_n}{2-x_n}$$
but idk how to proced from there, so how do i solve this? the fact $x_i>0$ makes me assume AM-GM inequality could be used but idk how one would use.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form).

Since $x_i\gt 0$ and $\sum_i x_i=1$, we also have $x_i\lt 1~\forall~i$ and the map $f\colon x\mapsto\dfrac x{2-x}$ is convex on $[0,1]$

We have,

$$\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{x_i}{2-x_i}=\sum_{\text{cyc}}f(x_i)\geq nf\left(\frac{\sum_i x_i}n\right)=nf(1/n)=n\frac{1/n}{2-1/n}=\frac n{2n-1}$$

with equality iff all the $x_i$'s are equal.

---

Alternatively, note that $\dfrac{x_i}{2-x_i}=\dfrac 1{\frac 2{x_i}-1}$ for $x_i\ne 0$; since $0\lt x_i\lt 1$ as well, we have $c_i=\dfrac 2{x_i}\gt 2$, or $c_i-1\gt 1$, or $0\lt\dfrac 1{c_i-1}\lt 1$

Now, use the HM-AM inequality on $\{c_i-1\}_i$ (more generally, the [power mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) inequality $M_{-1}\le M_1$).

Comment: This has been asked and answered before. I suggest to use [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7Bx_1%7D%7B1%2Bx_2%2Bx_3%2B%5Ccdots%2Bx_n%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx_2%7D%7B1%2Bx_1%2Bx_3%2B%5Ccdots%2Bx_n%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx_3%7D%7B1%2Bx_1%2Bx_2%2B%5Ccdots%2Bx_n%7D%2B%5Ccdots%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx_n%7D%7B1%2Bx_1%2Bx_2%2B%5Ccdots%2Bx_%7Bn-1%7D%7D%5Cge%5Cfrac%7Bn%7D%7B2n-1%7D%24) to search for duplicates, before answering a question. See also [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265/42969)

Comment: @MartinR: Thank you, indeed searching for a duplicate first would have been a better idea. I knew about Approach0 but I admit I didn't put effort into searching. Glad to see [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1) finally being enforced! :) Will do from next time. +1

Answer (score 0):

By C-S we obtain:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{1+\sum\limits_{k\neq i}x_k}=-n+\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{x_i}{1+\sum\limits_{k\neq i}x_k}+1\right)=-n+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2}{1+\sum\limits_{k\neq i}x_k}=$$
$$=-n+\frac{2}{2n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(1+\sum\limits_{k\neq i}x_k\right)\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\sum\limits_{k\neq i}x_k}\geq-n+\frac{2n^2}{2n-1}=\frac{n}{2n-1}.$$

Comment: welcome back sir!

Comment: It took me less than a minute to find an identical question with answers (using Approach0). How much effort did you put into searching for a duplicate?

Answer (score -3):

After OP's attempt, let
$$F=\frac{x_1}{2-x_1}+\frac{x_2}{2-x_2}+\frac{x_3}{2-x_3}+\cdots+\frac{x_n}{2-x_n}.$$
Let $x_1\ge x_2\ge x_3.....\ge x_n$, apply Tchebecheff's inequality that if $a_1\ge a_2 \ge a_3,....\ge a_n$ and $b_1 \ge b_2 \ge b_3 \ge ...\ge b_n$, then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_kb_k \ge  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k$$
Here let $x_1\ge x_2 \ge x_3,....\ge x_n$ then $(2-x_1)^{-1} \ge (2-x_2)^{-1} \ge (2-x_3)^{-1} \ge ...\ge (2-x_n)^{-1}$, so we write
$$F\ge \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k \sum_{k=1}^{n}  \frac{1}{2-x_k}$$
Next by AM-HM $\sum_k a_k \sum_k \frac{1}{a_k} \ge n^2$, we get
$$F\ge \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n x_k ~~ \frac{n^2}{2n-\sum_k x_k}=\frac{n}{2n-1}.$$

Comment: It took me less than a minute to find an identical question with answers (using Approach0). How much effort did you put into searching for a duplicate?

Comment: @Martin R To find whether a problem is duplicate  I mock as if I am asking/posting this problem then some times only REVIEW your question works.  also  It is not guaranteed if it is there. Do you know any other method please suggest. There should be a "search" section where we can find things of our interes in MSE. Fior instance I want to search results having Frullani integral. Please suggest how can I find it.

Comment: See [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265/42969). – Approach0 and SearchOnMath work very well.

Comment: @ZAhmed Google search "frullani integral site:math.stackexchange.com". Search once, search harder, search even harder, then answer. Ideally more time should be spent searching and redirecting, than answering. In fact, the only reason why searching is so difficult is because of rampant duplication in the first place, which creates many copies of the same concept and then people don't know where to search for what.

Comment: It is a big problem that newbies are not introduced to these two engines : half their job will be done if they use the engines to search, rather than wait for an answer. If people genuinely want to help users over gaining reputation, then all you need to do is find a duplicate on the site and then redirect them there. They get an explanation rather than having to wait for one, and you have helped them without expending too much effort.

Comment: What happened to the civility?